# Compare string to date in access

Tags: ms-access

i have a date called aDate in the formatted as string "yyyy-mm-dd", and I am trying to compare that with a date. Here is what i have tried.

```
datevalue(aDate) > #1/1/16#
```

And

```
datevalue(Str(aDate)) > #1/1/16#
```

But I always get this error:  "Data type mismatch in criteria expression"

Comment: I can't replicate this. Check the date for any non-ascii characters by copy-pasting it into the immediate window. Provide further information of the source of your actual date.

Comment: There is a lot of unnecessary guessing when the code both declaring and assigning aDate should be posted.  It would also be prudent to include the full statement that includes the comparison currently shown in the question.  Maybe the error is not about the date, but perhaps order of operations is not being properly defined, for instance with proper parenthesis.

Answer (score 1):

> there are no "" in the data. It shows as 2012-12-13

Don't know how you do, but it seems like you build this expression:

```
DateValue(2012-12-13) > #1/1/16#
```

which will evaluate to:

```
DateValue(1987) > #1/1/16#
```

which will raise the error you see.

So adjust your code to create:

```
DateValue("2012-12-13") > #1/1/16#
```